# Chrome Extension opens a panel in a loop, doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, panel

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that will not open on popup, but in a panel.

The JavaScript is

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url:"PrincipalOnlineC2C.html",
    type:"panel",
    width:350,
    height:400
});
```

The problem with this is that when I open the Extension, it never stops creating new panels. How do I do to open just one panel?

Comment: Without seeing a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question, I can only guess 1) you include the js file that creates the panel inside PrincipalOnlineC2C.html or 2) you have a listener somewhere for navigations/updates/windows that ultimately invokes that code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, half way, just added a button that triggers the function.

```js
window.onload = function () {

document.getElementById("abrirPanel").addEventListener("click", abrir);

    function abrir() {
        chrome.windows.create({
            url:"PrincipalOnlineC2C.html",
            type:"panel",
            width:400,
            height:550
        });
    }
}
```